# Select row that is within start date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm writing a PHP application that shows promotions for a certain time frame.

In the application you can set the start date and end date. There can at some points be a time where there is no promotion showing.

In my database I'm storing

```
date_from (MySQL DATE - eg 2011-03-05) //start date
```

and

```
date_to (MySQL DATE - eg 2011-03-08) //end date
```

The user can setup multiple promotions that automatically switch over to the next date.

With the above example dates the offer will show on the 5th,6th and 7th.

I imagine I need something along the lines of

```
SELECT * FROM promotions WHERE date_from > $current_date
```

But how would I ensure it wouldn't show on the 8th and then (if there was a promotion starting on the 8th) show the new one.

**EDIT:**

This SQL as suggested by Krtek doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT * FROM promotions WHERE 2011-03-08 BETWEEN date_from AND date_to LIMIT 1
```

The row holds the following data date_from = '2011-03-01' and date_to = '2011-03-09' yet nothing is returned

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM promotions WHERE '$current_date' BETWEEN date_from AND date_to
```

edit: added the quotes around the date, it should work better like this.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working... on this row date_from = '2011-03-01' and date_to = '2011-03-09'. $current_date = '2011-03-08' it doesn't select a row

Comment: in your edited code 2011-03-08 is a mathematical expression which give 2000... Try putting it in quotes in the query. But maybe you'll have to use some Date function like strtotime()

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM promotions WHERE date_from > $current_date and date_to < $current_date ;
```

if you want to go for day based date, the query becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM promotions WHERE DATE(date_from) > $current_date and DATE(date_to) < $current_date ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM promotions WHERE date_from <= $current_date and date_to >= $current_date
```

because people usually expect it to start ON the date specified and end up to and including the date specified.

But krtek's answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM `promotions` WHERE date_from between $date_from and $date_to
```

http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/between-date.php

Answer (score 0):

Please, no not use string interpolation when building SQL queries. You *will* regret it.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT * FROM promotions WHERE ? BETWEEN date_from AND date_to");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $current_date);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```